# С. Сравнение дат

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста. Считываю из файла строки в виде (Алексей - 22 Декабря 1995). Нужно отсортировать эти строки по датам. Не могу придумать, как это сделать, кроме как найти месяц в строке и отправить в функцию, в которой перебирать все даты, что-то вроде этой:

```
int get_month(char *mon)
{
    ...
    if(strcmp(mon=="Декабря"){
        return 12;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Это будет самое разумное :) Или писать функцию сравнения названий месяцев...

Comment: @Harry А как сразу выделит месяц из строки? Есть какой-то просто способ? или нужно методом  подсчета пробелом искать?

Comment: Тут может проще оказаться через регулярные выражения достать все компоненты даты. Конечно, если шаблон строки будет строго соблюдаться.

Comment: *strptime()* и *strftime()* -- ваши друзья.

Answer (score 1):

```
int get_month(const char *month)
{
    static const char *m[] = {"Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", 
"Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        if (strcmp(month, m[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```